# Responsiveness of a button fails when window minimized, but it's brothers responsiveness don't fail

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web-deployment, responsive

So I have this Web UI in which I need 6 buttons to be responsive, 5 of them works pretty well but the last which needs to be placed further right(Button 6 in the image), does not looks how it must suppose to work. When the window is maximized everything looks good:

[Maximized window (Looking good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27E16.png)

When the window is minimized it tries to stays in sight but it makes it to a point where it crashes with the other buttons instead of just giving up, and, like the the other buttons, just do what you can see in the next image:

[Button 5 doing it right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1sgA.png)

Instead, the button 6 does this:

[Button 6 failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdLtw.png)

So basically, I can't find a way to make button 6 behaves like the others.
This is my html:

```
  <div style="display:flex">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      1111
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      2222222
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      3333333
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      44444
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">555555</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn" id="btnSix">
      6666 6666666 66666666
    </button>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .pin-ready-btn { margin-right: 22px !important; width: auto !important; }

#btnSix{ position: absolute !important; right: 70px !important; }
```

Thanks everyone for reading, taking the time and answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has one error, 2 closing  tags for 2nd button

And below is working code, hope this is what you need.

```
<style>
.btn-holder { display:flex; justify-content:flex-start;}
.btn-holder button { background:#00a7ef; font-size:15px; color:#fff; border:0; cursor:pointer; margin:0 20px 0 0; padding:10px; border-radius:3px;}
.btn-holder button:last-child { margin-left:auto;}
</style>

 <div class="btn-holder">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      1111
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      2222222
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      3333333
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">
      44444
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn">555555</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pin-ready-btn" id="Re-RunValidationBtn">
      6666 6666666 66666666
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error and for the answer, that actually worked! Can you explain to me the justify-context property?

Comment: justify-content is horizontal alignment, it's horizontal only if the the parent which is display:flex and has flex-direction as row (row is by default) if the flex-direction is changed to flex-direction: column it means vertical position of all child elements and then justify-content becomes vertical alignment property.

justify-content: flex-start; is left alignment
justify-content: center; center alignment
justify-content: flex-end; is right alignment
and there are more properties for justify-content, like space-around, space-between which are very useful.